# Writing temporary files in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am just curious about what is the behavior of temporary directory in an iPhone app.
(If my memory is correct there is a tmp directory in the same location as Documents)

What happen if I save some files there?, would they be deleted automatically when my app is terminated or should I do it manually? in that case What would it be the difference between Documents directory?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although temporary folder (path can be obtained using `NSTemporaryDirectory()` function) contents is not guaranteed to persist between application launches, but in general it is developer responsibility to remove unnecessary temp files. The differences from documents folder are:

- As mentioned above tmp folder contents can be deleted by system (but may not)
- tmp folder content is not backed up by itunes

Comment: whats the difference between saving content at document directory or temp?

Comment: @Rajneesh071, it is probably worth asking as a separate question. Basically, temporary folder can be cleared by system any time when disk space is needed. Also, Documents folder is backed up by iTunes and synced by iCloud